# Setting up Golang Environment on VC

Tags: visual-studio

VS code constantly shows me the box 'Cannot install Go tools. Set either go.gopath or go.toolsGopath in settings'. I open workspace settings and go to the Go configuration where I open the settings.json file for Gopath. What field do I type in there?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the following field in the settings. You can use any path in your system. This will contain the helper binaries go ecosystem such as linters.

[image: visual studio code go tools path]